# Creating one single lyr from two

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layer-file

I have two lyr and I want to create one single lyr (I want to unite into one).

Is it possible?

Comment: While it's certainly possible to put two layers (represented by two `.lyr` files) into one layer file, that will not make one layer, just two grouped layers. Please [Edit] the Question to provide context to your goal, so we can determine if this is an XY Problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the lyr you refer to are layer file (*.lyr) in ArcGIS Desktop the simplest way is to :

1. Add both your lyr file in a new ArcGIS MXD
2. Group them (select both of them, right click > Group)
3. Export the group as a new lyr (right click on the group then save as
   layer file)